# Frida hook multiple processes

Tags: windows, python, frida

There was such a situation. I run the frida hook on the process like this:

```
frida -f '..\hack2\hackme.exe'  -l .\start.js
```

In the script itself I do this

```
var moduleData = Process.getModuleByName("hackme.exe");
```

then comes the code which, as a result of which, I launch a function that launches another process - `level2.exe`.

It would be convenient if you could hook this process directly from this script.
calling `Process.findModuleByName("level2.exe");` is always null. The only way I see now is to write a Python script that will monitor the launch of the second process and run the hook in different threads. Perhaps there is a simpler solution without resorting to such extreme measures?

Comment: In difference to a common debugger the Frida JavaScript code is running inside the hooked process, this means you can not simply access a different process. BTW: `findModuleByName` can only find libraries loaded into the current process, therefore it will never find level2.exe unless it is not started/executed but loaded as library into the current process. I don't see a different way than hooking the seconds process using an external Python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [child-gating](https://frida.re/news/#child-gating) and frida has a very good [example](https://github.com/frida/frida-python/blob/main/examples/child_gating.py)

Here is a demo with a simple application. A simple C program with a `fork` and we try to hook `puts` for both child and parent.

```
(test3) [frida-example] cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
  puts("before");
  pid_t pid = fork();
  if (pid) {
    puts("parent");
  } else {
    puts("child");
  }
}
(test3) [frida-example] make test
cc     test.c   -o test
```

With the [example](https://github.com/frida/frida-python/blob/main/examples/child_gating.py) - adding changes

```
    def _start(self):
        argv = ["./test"]
        print("✔ spawn(argv={})".format(argv))
        pid = self._device.spawn(argv, env={}, stdio='pipe')
        self._instrument(pid)
```

and

```
    def _instrument(self, pid):
        print("✔ attach(pid={})".format(pid))
        session = self._device.attach(pid)
        session.on("detached", lambda reason: self._reactor.schedule(lambda: self._on_detached(pid, session, reason)))
        print("✔ enable_child_gating()")
        session.enable_child_gating()
        print("✔ create_script()")
        script = session.create_script("""\
Interceptor.attach(Module.getExportByName(null, 'puts'), {
  onEnter: function (args) {
    send({
      type: 'puts',
      path: Memory.readUtf8String(args[0])
    });
  }
});
""")
```

then by running

```
(test3) [frida-example] python hook.py
✔ spawn(argv=['./test'])
✔ attach(pid=1968)
...
✔ resume(pid=1968)
⚡ message: pid=1968, payload={'type': 'puts', 'path': 'before'}
⚡ message: pid=1968, payload={'type': 'puts', 'path': 'parent'}
...
⚡ child_added: Child(pid=1977, parent_pid=1968, origin=fork)
✔ attach(pid=1977)
...
✔ resume(pid=1977)
⚡ child_removed: Child(pid=1977, parent_pid=1968, origin=fork)
⚡ message: pid=1977, payload={'type': 'puts', 'path': 'child'}
...
⚡ detached: pid=1977, reason='process-terminated'
```

We hooked both the instances of child and parent